# SQL Server Database log file max size setting problem

Tags: sql-server

Database was created with initial log file size 50 MB and max size set to 2 GB.
While restoring database from pre production environment to test environment, it failed due to transaction log file full due to "ACTIVE_TRANSACTION".
I increased max size to 100 GB. But after restore database, the max size is set to 2 GB again automatically.

Can you please help out how this max size changes automatically. Please advise if any settings modifies this max size of log file after restore happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a fresh backup after changing the max size?   This would be defined in the backup file - you can see with `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` which will give you the metatdata of the database files.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was changing the max size in the target database. As you suggested, verified the FILELISTONLY. The backup file has maxsize 2 GB only. it fixed the issue while changing in the source database log file max size. Thanks again.